# How do I adjust this code so that I can enter how many runs I want and it will store each run in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have created this code to generate a 1 set of lottery numbers, but I am trying to make it so that the user can enter how many sets they want (input n), and it will print out as one long matrix of size nX6?  I was messing around with a few options from online suggestions, but to no avail.  I put the initial for i=1:1:n at the beginning, but I do not know how to store each run into a growing matrix.  Right now it still generates just 1 set.

```
function lottery(n)

for i=1:1:n
    xlow=1;
    xhigh=69;
    m=5;
    i=1;

    while (i<=m) 
        lottonum(i)=floor(xlow+rand*(xhigh-xlow+1));

        flag=0;
        for j=1:i-1
            if (lottonum(i)==lottonum(j)) 
                flag=1;
            end
        end
        if flag==0   
            i=i+1;
        end
    end

    ylow=1;
    yhigh=26;
    m=1;
    lottonum1=floor(ylow+rand*(yhigh-ylow+1));
    z = horzcat(lottonum, lottonum1);
end

disp('The lotto numbers picked are')
fprintf('%g ',z)
disp ('  ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not storing or displaying the newly generated numbers, only the last set. To solve this, initialize `z` with NaNs or zeros, and later index `z` to store each set in a row of `z`, by using `z(i,:) = lottonum`.

However, you are using `i` as iterator in the while loop already, so you should use another variable, e.g. `k`.

You can also set `z` as an output of the function, so you can use this matrix in some other part of a program.

```
function z = lottery(n)
% init z
z = NaN(n,6);

for k = 1:n
    xlow=1;
    xhigh=69;
    m=5;
    i=1;
    while (i<=m) 
        lottonum(i)=floor(xlow+rand*(xhigh-xlow+1));
        flag=0;
        for j=1:i-1
            if (lottonum(i)==lottonum(j)) 
                flag=1;
            end
        end
        if flag==0   
            i=i+1;
        end
    end
    ylow=1;
    yhigh=26;
    lottonum1 = floor(ylow+rand*(yhigh-ylow+1));
    z(k,:) = horzcat(lottonum, lottonum1);  % put the numbers in a row of z
end

disp('The lotto numbers picked are')
disp(z)  % prettier display than fprintf in this case.
disp ('  ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The nice answer from *rinkert* corrected your basic mistakes (*like trying to modify your loop iterator `i` from within the loop => does not work*), and answered your question on how to store all your results.

This left you with a working code, however, I'd like to propose to you a different way to look at it.

The porposed architecture is to divide the tasks into separate functions:

- One function `draw_numbers` which can draw `N` numbers randomly (and does only that)
- One function `draw_lottery` which call the previous function as many times as it needs (your `n`), collect the results and display them.

---

### `draw_lottery`

This architecture has the benefit to greatly simplify your main function. It can now be as simple as:

```
function Draws = draw_lottery(n)

    % define your draw parameters
    xmin   =  1 ; % minimum number drawn
    xmax   = 69 ; % maximum number drawn
    nballs =  5 ; % number of number to draw

    % pre allocate results
    Draws = zeros( n , nballs) ;

    for iDraw=1:1:n
        % draw "nballs" numbers
        thisDraw = draw_numbers(xmin,xmax,nballs) ;

        % add them to the result matrix
        Draws(iDraw,:) = thisDraw ;
    end

    disp('The lotto numbers picked are:')
    disp (Draws)
    disp ('  ')

end
```

---

### `draw_numbers`

Instead of using a intricated set of `if` conditions and several iterators (`i`/`m`/`k`) to branch the program flow, I made the function *recursive*. It means the function may have to call *itself* a number of time until a condition is satisfied. In our case the condition is to have a set of `nballs` **unique** numbers.
The function:

- (1) draws `N` integer numbers randomly, using [`randi`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html).
- (2) remove duplicate numbers (if any). Using [`unique`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).
- (3) count how many unique numbers are left `Nu`
- (4a) if `Nu = N` => exit function
- (4b) if `Nu < N` => Call itself again, sending the existing `Nu` numbers and asking to draw an additional `N-Nu` numbers to add to the collection. Then back to step (2).

in code, it looks like that:

```
function draw = draw_numbers(xmin,xmax,nballs,drawn_set)

    % check if we received a partial set
    if nargin == 4
        % if yes, adjust the number of balls to draw
        n2draw    = nballs - numel(drawn_set) ;
    else
        % if not, make a full draw
        drawn_set = [] ;
        n2draw    = nballs ;
    end

    % draw "nballs" numbers between "xmin" and "xmax"
    % and concatenate these new numbers with the partial set
    d = [drawn_set , randi([xmin xmax],1,n2draw)] ; 

    % Remove duplicate
    drawn_set = unique(d) ;

    % check if we have some more balls to draw
    if numel(drawn_set) < nballs
        % draw some more balls 
        draw = draw_numbers(xmin,xmax,nballs,drawn_set) ;
    else
        % we're good to go, assign output and exit funtion
        draw = drawn_set ;
    end
end
```

---

You can have both functions into the same file if you want.
I encourage you to look at the documentation of a couple of Matlab built-in functions used:

- [`randi`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html)
- [`unique`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html)